# Как в Angilarjs из контроллера вида передать значение переменной в контроллер директивы?

Tags: angularjs

Имеется обычный контроллер вида, а так же директива нужно передать значение $scope из контроллера в контроллер директивы

Контроллер вида

```
testControllers.controller('GalleryCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$routeParams',
    function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $routeParams) {


    }
]);
```

Директива

```
testControllers.directive('galleryform', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function ($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope) {


        },
        templateUrl: 'partials/gallery/editform.html'
    };
});
```

Comment: Можете добавить код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

по умолчанию директива не создает свой $scope, а пользуется $scope контроллера.
вам стоит убрать переопределение scope в коде директивы

```
scope: {},
```

и тогда все заработает автоматически.